# What is real purpose of BETWEEN clause in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For proper use of indices, you must make filter predicate as a search argument, so you can't use `DATETIME` functions in this case.

You need to use `<=` and `>=` operands for date and time comparisons, but there is also the `BETWEEN` clause.

So, recommendations is to use simple arithmetical operands, because `BETWEEN` has problem with end dates.

Is there any context where `BETWEEN` is preferable to `<=` and `>=`?

Comment: `BETWEEN` is just shorthand for a closed range comparison. `BETWEEN` works fine for date comparisons. There's really not much difference. Is your question really about why someone told you not to use `BETWEEN` for date comparisons?

Comment: No, no one told me to not use BETWEEN, but my conclusion is that arithmetical operands are enough good, so my logical question was why BETWEEN clause is included. Readability is one reason, but if is only that, I am little suspicious that is redundant...

Comment: Then why do you claim that "`BETWEEN` has problems with end dates"? It works just fine. The only benefit `BETWEEN` has is readability, and that benefit is subjective and therefore debatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, recommendations is to use simple arithmetical operands, because
>   **BETWEEN has problem with end dates**.

No. BETWEEN doesn't have a problem with end dates (for date and time values) but developers because some people forget that a date and time (the **DATETIME** data type) value has, also, a time component.

So, writing

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyDateTimeColumn BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20130113'
```

is  wrong when you want to show all records between these two dates because `'20130113'` means `'20130113 00:00:00.000'` (and not `'20130113 23:59:59.997'`) and `BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20130113'` means `BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20130113 00:00:000.000'`.

Some solutions:

1)

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyDateTimeColumn BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20130113 23:59:59.997'
```

2)

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, MyDateTimeColumn) BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20130113'
```

3)

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '20120103'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '20120103'

SET @EndDate = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @EndDate)+1))

SELECT @StartDate AS [SD], @EndDate [ED]

SELECT ...
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyDateTimeColumn BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Results:

```
SD                      ED
----------------------- -----------------------
2012-01-03 00:00:00.000 2012-01-03 23:59:59.997

(1 row(s) affected)

...
```

Note: `DATETIME` values are ["rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

Comment: You are correct.  SQL doesn't have a problem with the Between operator, developers do!  I prefer to NEVER use the between operator on dates.  I completely understand the rounding issues with the DateTime data type.  The problem I have with this code is that it  relies on the underlying data type.  If you were to change the data type of the column to SmallDateTime without changing the code, you would end up with an index scan instead of a seek because of the conversion from smalldatetime to datetime.  Likewise, the code wouldn't work if you changed the data type of the column to DateTime2.

Comment: Changing data type from `DATETIME` to `SDT` or `DT2` can bring more (and bigger) problems than you have presented, problems unrelated to OP's question and my answer. In any instance, the developer should check  for all *side effects* after this data type change.

Comment: Fortunately, SQL Server has tools that allow to find [almost] all server side code that references that column. More, if the column's data type is `DT` then , is very likely that also, the data type used for stored procedure parameters will be [also] `DT`. And, if the column's data type is changed from `DT` to `SDT` then, the developr will have to change, also, the stored procedure parameter's data type from `DT` to `SDT`, otherwise he will have the same problem: index scan (`SDTColumn >= @Start_DT AND SDTColumn < @End_DT`).

Answer (score 6):

If you are asking if there is any difference between

```
where X between 1 and 10
```

versus

```
where X >= 1 and X <= 10
```

then no, there is no difference.  It is just a convenient enhancement to the language, one of many that try to make life easier; a `BETWEEN` expression very clearly expresses the desired result.

It's similar to the `COALESCE` function, which is just a quicker way to write a `CASE` expression that checks for `NULL` values.

Comment: And similar behaviour to `COALESCE` [when using an expression which is a sub query too](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2008/06/27/subqueries-in-between-and-case-statements.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It is beneficial for readability when using numeric types.

If you need to check for an integral column value between two integral values:

```
theColumn BETWEEN 5 and 25
```

Comment: OK, readability may be one reason, but is that enough to include new things just for better formatted code?

Comment: @veljasije - New? `BETWEEN` is standardized.

Comment: I know it is, but why adding new stuff to standard if there only reason is readability?

Comment: What I want to say is that I am a confused a bit, because, obviously I cannot find real purpose of clause...

Comment: @veljasije - That's like asking why there is a `do` or `while` loop, when you can just have a `for` loop. Readability matters.

Answer (score 1):

BETWEEN gets translated into two separate operation connected with or: `a BETWEEN b AND c` is equivalent to `a >= B AND a <= c`. Equivalent in this context means functionally equivalent. It will produce the same behavior in the optimizer and the execution engine.

The problem lies in the fact that the word between in natural languages is fuzzy. If it is meant with or without inclusion of the boundaries depends on a lot of factors that are not always obvious. Fuzzy behavior we need to keep away from programming.

While the T-SQL BETWEEN has a well defined behavior, it is easy to forget which one it is. Because code is read much more often than it is written, it is important to make it as readable as possible. Every time a reader encounters the BETWEEN keyword (s)he has to stop and think about the boundary behavior. That is distracting and also leads to hard to find bugs.

The reason you heard that there is a problem with the end boundary in date calculations is, that that is the case were people get the use of BETWEEN wrong most often.